# How to use OpenGL in Android Webview Kotlin Project?

Tags: android, kotlin, webview

I'm trying to use jitsi meeting i frame API in android webview, but it's virtual background feature is not running in the app. But it's working properly in chrome browser in same same device. So, am I missing any configuration of webview? Please help me out with this how I can achive this in kotlin. And how to integrate WebView with OpenGL.

I have tried to enable hardware acceleration. But nothing happened

Comment: Possibly related: [how to allow jitsi meeting on mobile browser using webview? I am Externel jitsi api. #5773](https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet/issues/5773)

Comment: @MorrisonChang thanks for the answer. But my issue is not listed in the link you provided. In my case meeting is working perfectly only the virtual background is not working. I mean it's not detecting humans. Instead, it's showing a virtual background image only.